# Best way to return status from long running Rails controller function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the preferred way in Rails 3 to send back status to the user for a long running application?

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is advisable to perform lengthy tasks in a background process, and return from the main function as soon as possible / immediately.

Check out the answers for [Ruby on Rails: How to run things in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897605/ruby-on-rails-how-to-run-things-in-the-background) and [Background processing in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804947/background-processing-in-rails) to know about some of the options for background processing with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Have that long running application write it's status to a fixed location where it is readable by Rails.  The status is usually of two forms, an ever increasing number in the range of 1 - 100, used for progress display,  or a status, i.e. 'reading, processing, writing'.

Then you have to develop an AJAX controller action that will read that file.  Create a corresponding javaScript file run when the AJAX action fires.

i.e. in app/controllers/some_controller.rb

```
def get_status
  @status = File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/lrp_status.txt","rb") { |f| f.read } 
end
```

Then in app/views/some/get_status.js.erb:

```
$('#my_status_div').html('<p> the status is <%= @status %></p>');
```

Then you have to set up some javascript using your preferred timer javascript thingy.  The point here is to every (? 1 second),  fire off that get_status AJAX call.

Comment: I posted a somewhat simplified example,  not taking into account there might be MULTIPLE processes running on behalf of different users.  That's an esay mod if you're interested.